# how to define angular methods

Tags: function, methods, controller

I'm a regular consumer of advice from Stackoverflow. It's an invaluable tool - thanks for all the help!

But this is my first question: I'm very new to Angular but I've been doing server side stuff for donkeys years.

I've got a method on a controller, which calls a server REST service. My problem is that the method is called whenever the controller is instantiated. I know there's got to be another way of declaring the function, but I've got no idea of what to search for.

Here's my html:

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="mLS" ng-controller="mLSController">
<head>....</head>
...
<li><a ng-if="userName" ng-click="Logout()">logout</a></li>
```

and my module (the module def is elsewhere, but it seems ok)

```
var app = angular.module('mLS');
app.controller('mLSController', function ($scope, $http, $window, $location) {
    $http({
        url: '/api/UI/GetUsername',
        method: 'GET'
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.userName = data;
        $scope.desiredPath = $location.path();

        if (!$scope.userName && $scope.desiredPath != '/Account/Login')
            $window.location.href = '/Account/Login';
    });
});

function Logout($http) {
    $http({ url: '/api/UI/Logout', method: 'GET' });
}
//app.
//  controller('mLSController', function ($scope, $http) {
//      $scope.Logout = function () {
//          $http({ url: 'api/UI/Logout', method: 'GET' });
//      };
//  });

//app.
//  controller('mLSController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Logout', function ($scope, $http, Logout) {
//      $scope.callLogout = function () {
//          Logout();
//      };
//  }]).
//  factory('Logout', ['$http', function (protocol) {
//      protocol({ url: 'api/UI/Logout', method: 'GET' }).success(function() {
//          $scope.Logout = true; });
//  }]);
```

So my problem is that the current code:

```
    function Logout($http) {
        $http({ url: '/api/UI/Logout', method: 'GET' });
}
```

just isn't called at all, and if I put it on the controller, `Logout()` is called when the controller is instantiated. Which isn't ideal.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the Logout function to be exposed to DOM (via Angular), you need to put it on $scope. There is no other option to call it using angular directives (ng-click).

Else, if you want it to be called before your app/controller are instantiated, use native javascript's onclick() event.

Warning: if you use onclick, you cannot set $scope variables.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to Bharat, I've got it working!

This is the solution:

```
    var app = angular.module('mLS');
    app.controller('mLSController', 


        //  function added to the controller
        function ($scope, $http, $window, $location) {
            $scope.Logout = function () {
                $http({ url: 'api/UI/Logout', method: 'GET' });
            return ;
        };


    $http({ url: '/api/UI/GetUsername', method: 'GET' }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.userName = data;
        $scope.desiredPath = $location.path();

        if (!$scope.userName && $scope.desiredPath != '/Account/Login')
            $window.location.href = '/Account/Login';
    });
});
```

For completeness, I could wrap the GetUsername call in a function, but the question is answered.

I can't upvote your answer, Bharat, because I haven't asked enough questions yet, but thanks so much!

Comment: No problems mate :)